# PHP : upload file to sharepoint via microsoft dynamics crm using curl in php

Tags: php, sharepoint, curl, file-upload, crm

I am trying to upload files to the microsoft dynamics crm using php, for this I have integrated microsoft sharepoint to the crm. I have used curl for uploading the file to the sharepoint via crm but am getting 411 or 401 http error while executing the curl script.i am new to curl.Please help

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors','On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        $process = curl_init();
        $username = 'xxx';
        $password = 'xxx';
        $filename = $_FILES['ecosFile']['name'];
        $filedata = $_FILES['ecosFile']['tmp_name'];
        $filesize = $_FILES['ecosFile']['size'];
        $post = array('file' => new CurlFile($filedata), "filename" => $filename);
        print_r($post);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://crmsharepoint.XXX/sites/xxx/application/Forms/?RootFolder=xxx'); 
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);                                                                           
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data', 'Content-Length:50'));        
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);                                                
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);     
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);    
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                                                        
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);                                                                
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $response = curl_exec($process); 
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($process); 
        curl_close($process);
        echo '<pre>';print_r($resultStatus);
        if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
            echo "hi".$response;
        } else {
             echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
        }
    }
?>

<div>
   <form action="testingcrm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <input type="file" name="ecosFile" id="ecosFile">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">   
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you found any answer..I need solution for this

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the errors because you need to authenticate to SharePoint. Are you using SharePoint Online or On Premises. I don't think it will be possible for you to use PHP for the solution, unless you can handle with custom code with the URL redirects when you authenticate to O365.

I had a similar requirement, using Excel to upload to SharePoint and I designed VBA code to connect to SharePoint online, it was hard to maintain and it broke. I recommend you to create a .NET app  were you pass the information i.e. (document library, source folder, user name, password, sharepoint site url) and that will work.

I have Microsoft.SharePoint,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime in project references on Visual Studio and it works like charm.